# Cannot deserialize the current JSON object to generic List type

Tags: c#, json, json.net

**Question Background:**

I'm using Newtonsofts JSON.NET to desearlize an XML response from a AWS service to a C# object strcuture.

**The Issue:**

I'm receiving the following error message when trying to deserialize on the `ImageSet` class `Category` property :

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ShoppingComparisonEngine.AWS.AWSRootListPriceObject.ImageSet]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

Path 'Items.Item[1].ImageSets.ImageSet.Category', line 1, position 12122.
```

I should add I have no control over the returned XML and in turn have no control over the large object structure I need to deserialize the response into.

**The Code:**

```
var awsPriceLostModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AwsListPriceRootObject>(fullyEscapedData);
```

The following is the C# class model for 'ImageSet'

```
public class ImageSets
{
    [JsonProperty("imageset")]
    public List<ImageSet> ImageSet { get; set; }
}

public class ImageSet
{
    [JsonProperty("category")]
    public string Category { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("swatchimage")]
    public SwatchImage SwatchImage { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("smallimage")]
    public SmallImage2 SmallImage { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("thumbnailimage")]
    public ThumbnailImage ThumbnailImage { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("tinyimage")]
    public TinyImage TinyImage { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("mediumimage")]
    public MediumImage2 MediumImage { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("largeimage")]
    public LargeImage2 LargeImage { get; set; }
}
```

This a screenshot showing the JSON response with the  `Category` property highlighted that is throwing the error:

[image]

Any help trying to work out why there is an error being thrown on desearlizing the list from JSON to C# will be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994685/how-to-handle-both-a-single-item-and-an-array-for-the-same-property-using-json-n)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your raw JSON looks like, but I'd try one of two things:

1. Use the `[JsonArray]`attribute [(docs)](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonArrayAttribute.htm) on your ImageSet property.

   ```
   [JsonArray]
   public List<ImageSet> ImageSet { get; set; }
   ```
2. Consider a different name for your ImageSet property, or the name that it is being serialized to. You've doubled up on the `ImageSet` name, using it represent the name of the class as well as the property that holds a list of that class.

Best of luck.